# Practical Skew Model For Equity Options?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, reference-request, volatility-skew, term-structure

I'm looking for a simple model I can use to calibrate equity implied volatility surface. There are several models published in the literature, and most of them seem far too sophisticated for my purposes. I'm just looking for something I can use out of the box given the raw implied vols (computed using Black-Scholes) for a set of option chains.

I imagine I'd first have to smooth out the curve using some kind of interpolation scheme, and then apply the skew model. What's the standard industry practice for this procedure? I'm just looking for a first order approximation that's better than using flat skew, i.e. ATM vol for all strikes.

Comment: How many degrees of freedom do you want? A simple scalar parameter controlling skew is OK?

Comment: Based on your requirements I'd say Gatheral's SVI model suffices for the interpolation and extrapolation part. There are several versions of SVI around now, the original one is probably the simplest and good enough for what you're looking for. When you say model, do you mean that after the inter and extrapolation you want a simple model to calibrate and then price exotic options with?

Comment: SVI will allow you to interpolate the IV curve in an arbitrage-free way. Then you're also interested in a "local" vol model which allows you to control skew right?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Thanks, yes, I realized that the OP probably wants more than just inter/extrap and I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm looking to calibrate a vol surface for a vanilla option chain, input a new ATM vol, and then output vol estimates for OTM strikes under the new ATM vol (assuming no changes in the curvature of skew).

Comment: But how precise do you want to be? For example, do you want your model to recover all vanilla option prices?

Comment: Or do you just want to play, with a simple model, with the effect of skew in implied vol surface?

Comment: I want to be able to recover the vols for all strikes after the change in ATM vol, so yes. I'd like to start with a toy model and extend if need be.

Comment: Well, SVI is a very sophisticated toy model, and based on your answer it should give you what you want. First calibrate the 5 parameters to an ATM option + 2 otm calls + 2 otm puts. Then change the level parameter value in the SVI model (which basically results in parallel shift). You can change the other params as well to play around with possible shapes of the smile.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it.